# How to make Javascript bitwise operators behave like in C?

Tags: javascript

In Javascript the following comparison:

```
(0xf0000000 & 0xf0000000) == 0xf0000000
```

is false since the bitwise operator converts to numbers to signed int32. The result of the `&` is a negative number and `0xf0000000` is a positive number

Is there a way to make it behave as I would expect it to behave in C?

Comment: A bit of a workaround, but you could always use `0xf0000000 | 0` to convert the right-hand side to a signed int32 as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Section 12.9.5 of Ecma 262 7.0](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/index.html#sec-unsigned-right-shift-operator) (ES 2016) defines the unsigned right shift operator (`>>>`) to return a unsigned 32-bit integer. This has been the case [at least since ES 5](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.7.3).

In other words, you can use this operator to turn a int32 value into a uint32 value when you shift by 0.

Therefore, you can simply change the expression to

```
(0xf0000000 & 0xf0000000) >>> 0 == 0xf0000000
```

which yields `true`.

Answer (score 1):

Use the XOR operator and compare with 0.

`(0xf0000000 & 0xf0000000) ^ 0xf0000000 === 0`

`A ^ B` will be `0` if `A === B`.